# Wix Project not available in VS 2017

Tags: wix

I've installed WiX Toolset Visual Studio 2017 Extension but still cannot find the Wix in Other Project Types. Is there anything else I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the version you have installed is not supported for 2017.

Try [this one](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RobMensching.WixToolsetVisualStudio2017Extension).

Comment: That is the version I have installed.

Comment: Any other suggestions? Anyone else having this problem?

Answer (score 0):

There's a VS 2017 update. Once installed Wix appeared.